# Rails 3 - Case Insensitive Query with Ransack & Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

My Rails app uses the [Ransack](https://github.com/ernie/ransack) gem to search my model on multiple attributes.  Is there a way to have Ransack make case insensitive queries to Postgres?

```
= search_form_for @q do |f|
  = f.label :name_cont
  = f.text_field :name_cont

  = f.label :code
  = f.text_field :code_eq

= f.submit
```

Comment: Have you got any work around for this issue?

Comment: no, but I haven't looked into it for many months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Posgres uses ILIKE for case insensitive queries.

From spovich on github:

> The LIKE vs ILIKE comes from ARel, not ransack. However, that doesn't
>   look like your issue.
>
> Your use of :code_eq will generate SQL for an exact match (e.g. 'where
>   code = "foo") thus cannot be case insensitive. Any of the 'like'
>   predicates (_cont, _start, _end) generate ILIKE by default (for
>   postgresql). So if you use :code_cont that will generate an ILIKE
>   statement (e.g. 'where code ILIKE "%foo%"'). See the constants for all
>   the predicates.
>
> https://github.com/ernie/ransack/blob/master/lib/ransack/constants.rb

https://github.com/ernie/ransack/issues/57#issuecomment-3472618

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the matches_any predicate. I haven't seen any docs or specs on it in the github repo, but this issue discusses it, https://github.com/ernie/ransack/issues/11

Comment: It appears that *matches_any* is used to pass an array of values.  The array elements are ORed together in the query, so records that match any of the array elements are returned.